# how can i save my image as base 64 into database

Tags: php, laravel, base64

I'm trying to save an image from a form into database. I tried this but it's not working:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $article = new article;
    $photo_articles = new photo_articles;
    // $type = new type;

    $article->NOM_ARTICLE = $request->NOM_ARTICLE;
    $article->DESCRIPTION_ARTICLE = $request->DESCRIPTION_ARTICLE;
    $article->id = auth()->user()->id;
    $article->TYPE_ARTICLE = $request->LABEL_TYPE;
    $article->save();

    $photo_articles->PHOTO_ARTICLE = base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->PHOTO_ARTICLE));
    $photo_articles->ID_ARTICLE = $article->ID_ARTICLE;

    $photo_articles->save();

    return;
}
```

Here is my form:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('addarticle.store') }}" class="contact_form text-center" id="contact_form">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <input type="text" class="contact_input" name="NOM_ARTICLE" placeholder="Nom d'article"
                       required="required">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <select class="contact_input" name="LABEL_TYPE">
                    @foreach($types as $type)
                        <option> {{$type->LABEL_TYPE}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div id="uploading" class="uploadfile">
                <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="250000"/>
                <input type="file" class="contact_input uploadFileInput" id="imagearticle" name="PHOTO_ARTICLE"
                       placeholder="Capture de votre article" name="fic" size=50 required="required"/>
                <p id="uploadtextid" class="uploadText">upload image</p>
                <img class="uploadImage" src="" id="displayedimage">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <textarea class="contact_textarea contact_input" name="DESCRIPTION_ARTICLE" placeholder="Description"
                      required="required"></textarea>
        </div>

        <button class="contact_button right" type="submit">Valider!</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

My image is in `$request->PHOTO_ARTICLE`.

Can someone show me how to save it as `base64`? I've searched a lot but without result.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to save the images to your database instead of saving them to the file system and just adding the path to the image in the database?

Comment: What´s the error you get?

Comment: @RossWilson i am working on a project wich they specify that all should be saved on database

Comment: Is this a school project or for a business?

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt here is the error it shows file_get_contents(taxi driver.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: Well, then your file does not exist. Make sure the path is correct

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt i didnt specify any path im working with database. as you can see the code is above

Comment: Still, your image cant be loaded, because php doesnt find it. Make sure the path to the image is correct. The error "No such file or directory" is pretty self-explainatory.

Comment: Please can you add the form to your question?

Comment: You can't use `file_get_contents` against a column in a database.

Comment: @Dave what can i use then ?

Comment: @RossWilson what form de you mean ?

Comment: Simply leave out the `file_get_contents`. AFAIK `$request->PHOTO_ARTICLE` will have the image already.

Comment: The form you're using to submit the image i.e. `<form></form>`

Comment: @Dave then how can i display it in a view ?

Comment: @RossWilson here it is i just added it as an answer on my post you can find the form below

Comment: @RossWilson  its a school project ( my project of the end of the year )

Comment: @OthmaneMessaoud In that case I would definitely go back to your teacher and make sure they want you to store the actual image data in the database and not the file system as this is not a normal (or recommended) thing to do at all.

Comment: @RossWilson hahahha, just to let you know i tried to save it in the file system but i got another problem if you are free i can tell you so you can help ( my english is bad i apologise )

Comment: @RossWilson i have some questions for you if you are free please

Comment: What are your questions?

Comment: @RossWilson i need a messagerie system in my project so i watched so many tuto's so finally i found code source in github, i want to import it in my project but i don't know how

Comment: That sounds like it is very much outside of the scope for this post. Please create a new question for this.

Comment: i feel bad when i ask such questions people understimate me with their comments

Answer (score 0):

When you're submitting a file with a form you have to set add the attribute
`enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the opening form tag:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="{{ route('addarticle.store') }}" class="contact_form text-center" id="contact_form">
```

otherwise it will only submit the name of the file and not the file itself.

Then in your route you would just need:

```
$photo_articles->PHOTO_ARTICLE = base64_encode(
    file_get_contents($request->file('PHOTO_ARTICLE')->path())
);
```

Comment: no errors. this is how i display it in my view <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ chunk_split(base64_encode($nouvelleannonce->PHOTO_ARTICLE)) }}" alt="">   the photo loaded in the database but its corrupted i think because when i  display it nothing shows but when i loaded my photo manually from phpmyadmin it shows.

Comment: @OthmaneMessaoud I've updated my answer. This should give you what you want.